# Can a user select their homepage theme on my Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, wordpress-theming

I'm running a self-hosted Wordpress site, and I'm about to change the homepage layout from a blog to a more magazine-type format.

I know that some users will prefer to still see the old format, and I'd like to offer this as an option - for visitors to be able to select a second index.php (for instance index-blog.php) as their default homepage for the site.

I assume cookies would allow this, but if that's not possible, perhaps logged-in users would have that ability?

I can't seem to find a plugin that would help with this, so I'd really appreciate any tips - as well as advice on how having 'two' homepages might affect SEO.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this programmatically see this [link](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-trick-change-theme-programatically).  You should also create a child theme for your main theme see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for how to do that.